# What is the canonical way to transform a Range<T> into a List<T>?

Tags: java, collections, guava

There are a few options, but I am not sure which is standard.

- Manually iterate from lower to upper bound
- ContiguousSet
- Something else?

Comment: @PatrickParker it is in the Google collections library

Comment: As long as you're in the Guava world, and your range has a defined domain, then ContiguousSet seems like the way to go... not sure what you mean by "canonical" though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that straightforward, but of course possible. Just create [`ContiguousSet<T>`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ContiguousSet.html), which is an [`ImmutableSortedSet`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedSet.html), and use method [`asList()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html#asList--), eg.:

```
Range<Integer> range = Range.closed(1, 5);
ContiguousSet<Integer> ourIntegers = ContiguousSet.create(range, DiscreteDomain.integers());
ImmutableList<Integer> ourIntegersList = ourIntegers.asList();
System.out.println(ourIntegers); // [1‥5]
System.out.println(ourIntegersList); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Note that you may want to stick with `ContiguousSet` (vs using list view), because 
the former does not actualy store each element in memory, and the latter does, which can be an issue with big ranges.